# Unable to load Embed youtube video in cordova- iphone app

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, youtube

I am trying to load a youtube video in a cordova app. Code is

```
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

It is working fine on android devices but not working on iphone(Os version 9.3).

I have tried with `class="youtube-player" type="text/html"`,but of no use.

Any ideas?